# Robot framework: No keyword with name 'Wait Until Element Contains' found

Tags: maven, selenium, testing, robotframework

From Robot framework documentation, I can see the keyword `Wait Until Element Contains`. I have the following keyword defined myself:

```
Wait for element content
    [Arguments]    ${elementti}    ${teksti}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${elementti}
    Wait Until Element Contains    ${elementti}    ${teksti}
```

However, the following error is throw

```
No keyword with name 'Wait Until Element Contains' found. Did you mean:
    Selenium2Library.Wait Until Title Not Contains
```

I'm using `robotframework-maven-plugin` `1.4.6`

Comment: What's your robotframework-selenium2library version (that's where this keyword comes from)?

Comment: I'm using `robotframework-selenium2library-java` `1.4.0.8`

Comment: Not my cup of coffee, I'm using the python bindings ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Looking at its source though, it's a) quite outdated, and b) that [keyword is not implemented](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/markusbernhardt/selenium2library/keywords/Waiting.java). Regretfully I cannot help you with the jython deployments of RF, but if you go that way and use the official lib, your problem will most probably be solved.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly highlighted by @Todor the 1.4 version you're using is quite old. The combined [Selenium and Robot java](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java#readme) download hasn't been updated since 2015. In the combined 1.4 version the keyword you're seeking isn't found in the [keyword documentation](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/markusbernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java/1.4.0.8/robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8-libdoc.html).

The current version of Robot Framework is 3.0.2. The current Jar version can be downloaded from Maven Central [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.robotframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22robotframework%22). This does not contain the Selenium Browser automation and as such might not fulfill your need.

If you're familiar with Jython, then this road will allow you to install the Python version of Selenium2Library and thus be compatible. There are some good tutorials on SO to help you set this up.